# Using Russian characters in URL query

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I want to load a URL in `UIWebView` using the value of `UITextField` in the URL query:

```
let texts = SearchBox.text!
let searchurl = "http://sngpoisk.ru/search-location/?search_keywords=\(texts)&search_location=&place_location=&latitude=&longitude="
let urls = NSURL(string:searchurl)
let ret = NSURLRequest(URL:urls!)
Browser!.loadRequest(ret)
```

But when `texts` contains Russian characters, an error occurs:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP , subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the runtime error is you unwrap an optional instance of the `NSURL`, which is actually `nil`.

The reason of `urls` is `nil` is `searchurl` string contains [invalid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) characters (outside of the 7-bit ASCII range). To be used in URL that characters should be percent-encoded.

**Swift 2** (I guess you are using that version):

```
let encodedTexts = texts.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
if let encodedTexts = encodedTexts {
    let searchurl = "http://sngpoisk.ru/search-location/?search_keywords=\(encodedTexts)&search_location=&place_location=&latitude=&longitude="
    let urls = NSURL(string:searchurl)
    if let urls = urls {
        let ret = NSURLRequest(URL:urls)
        Browser!.loadRequest(ret)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let encodedTexts = texts.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
if let encodedTexts = encodedTexts {
    let searchurl = "http://sngpoisk.ru/search-location/?search_keywords=\(encodedTexts)&search_location=&place_location=&latitude=&longitude="
    let urls = URL(string:searchurl)
    if let urls = urls {
        let ret = URLRequest(url:urls)
        Browser!.loadRequest(ret)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find Thank you very much

```
let texts = Searchd.text!
    let encodedTexts = texts.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    if let encodedTexts = encodedTexts {
        let searchurl = "http://sngpoisk.ru/search-location/?search_keywords=\(encodedTexts)&search_location=&place_location=&latitude=&longitude="
        let urls = NSURL(string:searchurl)
        if let urls = urls {
            let ret = NSURLRequest(URL:urls)
            Browser!.loadRequest(ret)
        }
    }
```